# Android: Stuck assigning a bitmap from Parse to an imageview

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, bitmap

I am a beginner at android, and I don't really know Java very well, but I have experience in programming in other languages. I am trying to make an ImageView display a Bitmap I downloaded from Parse. I want to make holder.eventImageFeed display the picture, but I can't work out how. I'm sure there is a really simple way to do it but I'm just not familiar enough with Java to work it out, and I have tried several approaches.

I understand that the Bitmap bmp is outside of the scope of the rest of the class, and holder doesn't work in the inner class, so how do I assign bmp to holder.eventImageFeed?

Here is my code:

```
public class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {
protected Context mContext;
protected List<ParseObject> mEvent;

public FeedAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> event){
    super(context, R.layout.feed_custom_layout, event);
    mContext = context;
    mEvent = event;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.feed_custom_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.usernameFeed = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernameFeedTextView);
        holder.eventNameFeed = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventNameFeedTextView);
        holder.eventImageFeed = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventFeedView);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    ParseObject eventObject = mEvent.get(position);

    //Username
    String username = eventObject.getString("eventCreator");
    holder.usernameFeed.setText(username);

    //Event Name
    String eventName = eventObject.getString("eventTitle");
    holder.eventNameFeed.setText(eventName);

    //Event Artwork
    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) eventObject.get("eventArtwork");
    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                // Decode the Byte[] into
                // Bitmap
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

//What do I do here?

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Solution from @Aakash - declared Viewholder holder as final and used holder.eventImageFeed.setImageBitmap(bmp); Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
holder.eventImageFeed.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

or you can use picasso to set image using image url.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(fileObject.getUrl()).into(holder.eventImageFeed);
```

Comment: holder.eventImageFeed.setImageBitmap(bmp); doesn't work, it tells me I can't access holder from an inner class without it being declared final

Comment: so declare it final, what's the issue